# Time-in in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub DTRTimeInBTN_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DTRTimeInBTN.Click
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Worker_Attendance([Time_In],[Employee _Name]) values (@TIn,@Ename)", con)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TIn", lblTime.Text.ToString)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ename", cbx_employee_fullname.Text)
    DTRTimeInBTN.Enabled = False
    DTRTimeOutBTN.Enabled = True
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

This is my code. When a employee is timing-in on a payroll system that I am developing right now. The combo box shows only the registered employee that can Login. When I click the Time-in button, it should store the employee username and the current time that the employee time-in. The problem is when I click the Time-in button the there is an error showing.

> OleDbException was unhanded You cannot add or change a record because
>   a related record is required in table 'Worker_Registration'.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your Worker_Attendance table has a foreign key in a column we can't see in your code or the Employee_name, this foreign key joins Worker_Attendance to Worker_Registration.

Start by looking at the relationships that are set up for your database. Go to the Tools menu and select Relationships. Look for any relationships between the Members table and the table you are trying to update. Look at which field(s) are used in the relationship(s). This will tell you which field is causing the problem in the table you're trying to update, you will need to fill it for the insert to work.